# Get posts order by ACF field value as title in Wordpres

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type: **club-member**
I would like to display a list of all members
and separate them by ACF value called: **region**
the region custom field is a text field with a dynamic value.

In the end, I should print something like this:

England (Dynamic "region" field within the post type "club-member")

- Member 1
- Member 2
- Member 3
- Member 4

USA (Dynamic "region" field within the post type "club-member")

- Member 5
- Member 6
- Member 7

I am using a regular get_posts:

```php
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'club-member',
    // 'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$club_members = get_posts( $args );

if ( $club_members ) {
    foreach ( $club_members as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        $post_title = $post->post_title;
        $region     = get_field( 'region' );
        // ACF

        ?>
        <h3><?php echo $post_title; ?></h3>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

In the end, I should get something like this:

```html
<h1>Region (with associated members)</h1>
<h3>Club member title</h3>
<h3>Club member title</h3>
<h3>Club member title</h3>
<h3>Club member title</h3>

<h1>Region (with associated members)</h1>
<h3>Club member title</h3>
<h3>Club member title</h3>
<h3>Club member title</h3>
<h3>Club member title</h3>
```

**Note: the value of the field "region" is dynamic and should be only printed once and grouped underneath all the posts sharing the same field value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the documentation of ACF [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/#2-multiple-custom-field-values-text-based-values), I added a new query on top to get all the regions which we loop through in the second query.

```
<?php 

// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'club-member',
);
$regions = array(); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

 if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        if(!in_array(get_field('region'), $regions)){
            array_push($regions, get_field('region'));
        }
     endwhile; 
    
 endif; 

 wp_reset_query(); 


$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'club-member',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR'
    )
);

foreach($regions as $region) {
    array_push($query['meta_query'], array(
        'key' => 'region',
        'value' => $region,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ));
} 
   
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $region =  get_field('region'); ?>
    <?php if (in_array($region, $regions)) { ?>
    <h1>
        <?php
            echo(get_field('region')); 
            $index = array_search($region, $regions);
            if($index !== FALSE){
                unset($regions[$index]);
            }
        ?>
    </h1>
    <?php } ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

Comment: what if my value is Dynamic. meaning - I can't set it in the loop to "England" or "USA" I need to get the dynamic value of the text entered by the client. it's a free text field. can be tomorrow: "Germany", "Japan" whatever..

Comment: Edited as requested!

Comment: One last thing if I may - what if I want to add another custom field called "country" and output it next to the name of the region (inside the H1 tag) is it possible?

Comment: So you're saying club-member has both "region" and "country", you should just change the echo function to something like echo(get_field('region').get_field('country')); "." is a concatenation operator and it allows you to attach 2 strings of text.